# Force user to use language route

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-translate

I am changing my application routes so that I can use subdirectories with gTLDs(example.com/de/) instead of URL params (example.com?loc=de). As It is in http://devzone.zend.com/1765/chaining-language-with-default-route/ , I used the following route configuration:

```
protected function _initRoutes() {

    $locale = $this->getResource('locale');

    // Create route with language id (lang)
    $routeLang = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            ':lang', array(
        'lang' => $locale->getLanguage()
            ), array('lang' => '[a-z]{2}')
    );

    // Now get router from front controller
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $front->getRouter();

    // Instantiate default module route
    $routeDefault = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module(
            array(), $front->getDispatcher(), $front->getRequest()
    );

    // Chain it with language route
    $routeLangDefault = $routeLang->chain($routeDefault);

    // Add both language route chained with default route and
    // plain language route
    $router->addRoute('default', $routeLangDefault);
    $router->addRoute('lang', $routeLang);

    // Register plugin to handle language changes
    $front->registerPlugin(new Sistema_Plugin_Language());
}
```

I am using baseUrl to whole website links.

However my old links(example.com/news/) returns an error saying "No route matched the request", How could I force the user or redirect the user to new URLs(example.com/en/news/)?